# MATLAB: How to use "Run Tests" or runtests() command

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I have created a test script Test1.m using classes located in a folder called "test".

```
  classdef Test1 < matlab.unittest.TestCase
  ... code...
  end
```

I can run the tests by entering in the command window:

```
run(Test1)
```

Some members of my team are familiar with clicking 'Run Tests' button (or the equivalent of runtests() in command window). However, `runtests("Test1.m")` does not work with the below error:

> Error using runtests    Do not know what to run. Try "unit" or
>   "acceptance"

Is it due to the folder structure? How may i be able to run test script with 'Run Tests' button.

**EDIT:**

what executing "which -all runtests" in the command line returns:

```
/Documents/another/path_to/runtests.m 

/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/toolbox/matlab/testframework/unittest/core/runtests.m % Shadowed
```

My test script is located in:

```
/Documents/path_to/test/Test1.m
```

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/runtests.html#namevaluepairarguments The documentation suggests that the first input is not the file

Comment: Also make sure that you don't run into char-array vs. String issues. `"Test1.m"`and `'Test1.m'` makes a difference.

In our systems (Windows, Matlab 2017b) we use runtests to execute all tests within the working directory, for larger test-runs however we use explicit test-suites. For me it is kind of unclear what you want.

Comment: I don't think this error message is coming from the runtests function that ships with MATLAB. What is the output of "which -all runtests"?

Comment: @AndyCampbell oh thanks, interesting its is actually pointing to folders where my test script is not located

Comment: Yes, it is this "other" runtests that is getting in the way. You will need to remove it from the path to get the behavior you expect form the framework runtests function

Comment: If removing it from the path is not a desirable option,  then you can still simply create the suite and run it by calling run(testsuite('Test1.m'))

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running the tests by calling the file, you have to [run them by calling the class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testsuite.fromclass.html#btqk21n-1):

```
run(TestSuite.fromClass(?Test1))
```

Just make sure Test1.m is on the path.